# Error setting an adminhtml from a frontend path

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, adminhtml, template, third-party-module

I'm using a third-party which set an `appendPaymentBlock` Observer method

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <payment_info_block_prepare_specific_information>
            <observers>
                <realex_payment_information>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>realex/observer</class>
                    <method>appendPaymentBlock</method>
                </realex_payment_information>
            </observers>
        </payment_info_block_prepare_specific_information>
        ...
    </events>
    ...
</adminhtml>
```

Basically, this method set a template:

```
public function appendPaymentBlock(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    ...

    $paymentInfoBlock
        ->setPayment($payment)
        ->setPaymentInfo($paymentData)
        ->setTemplate('realex/payment/info/payment-info.phtml');

    $block->append($paymentInfoBlock);
}
```

`payment-info.phtml` script is at  `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/` path.

This is causing me the following critical error:

```
CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/realex/payment/info/payment-info.phtml
```

**How I can get this template from adminhtml and not from frontend folder?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the $paymentInfoBlock class extends 
`Mage_Core_Block_Template` and not `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template`.

Specifically to your extension, replacing

`$blockType = 'core/template';`

with

`$blockType = 'adminhtml/template';` should do the trick.